# What is the difference between fn an defn in clojure?

Tags: clojure

Here are two of the ways to write functions in Clojure:

```
(defn foo [a b] (+ a b))
(fn foo [a b] (+ a b))
```

I can call them like so:

In the case of 'defn'

```
(foo 1 2)
```

In the case of 'fn'

```
((fn foo [a b] (+ a b)) 1 2)
```

'fn' doesn't seem to insert its optional name into the current scope, where 'defn' seems to do exactly that. Is there any other difference or reason for having two ways of creating functions? Is there a reason we don't just use 'fn' like this:

```
(fn foo [a b] (+ a b))
(foo 1 2)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`defn` is *basically* defined as*:

```
(defmacro defn [name args & body]
  `(def ~name (fn ~args ~@body)))
```

Or in other words, you could *basically* write:

```
(defn my-func [a]
  (stuff a))
```

As*:

```
(def my-func
  (fn [a] (stuff a)))
```

Using just `fn` creates an anonymous function that alone isn't bound to any symbol externally. It must be bound using `let` or `def` to be referred to outside of itself.

By having `defn` defined in terms of `def` and `fn`, the responsibilies of binding a function to a symbol (as well as all the other complexities that come with it) and handling function behaviour can be separated.

When you supply a name for `fn`, it can't be referred to outside of the function, but it can be used to refer to itself to create a recursive anonymous function:

```
(fn my-func [n] (my-func (inc n))
```

And, it gives the function a slightly nicer name to show up in stack traces to ease debugging:

```
(defn my-func []
  ((fn my-inner-func [] (/ 1 0))))
=> #'digital-rain.core/my-func

(my-func)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: Divide by zero
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.divide(Numbers.java:158)
    at clojure.lang.Numbers.divide(Numbers.java:3808)
    at digital_rain.core$my_func$my_inner_func__2320.invoke(form-init1838550899342340522.clj:2)
    at digital_rain.core$my_func.invokeStatic(form-init1838550899342340522.clj:2)
    at digital_rain.core$my_func.invoke(form-init1838550899342340522.clj:1)
```

---

`*` These are gross understatements and a tad misleading, but they simplify things.

In reality, `defn` isn't defined using `defmacro`; `defmacro` is actually defined using `defn`. `defn` also adds some good stuff like pre/post condition checking, documentation, and other meta information; but that's not as relevant here. I recommend looking over its [source](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/131c5f71b8d65169d233b03d39f7582a1a5d926e/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L283) for a more in-depth look; although it's pretty convoluted. The fundamental guts of `clojure.core` can be a little daunting to wrap your head around.

Comment: And in case of (fn foo [a b] (+ a b)), this is still anonymous function, and foo can be used inside of the body of the function if you need to recursively call anonymous function itself.

Comment: @BojanHorvat Yes, I think I originally meant to add a blurb about that, but it didn't make the cut. I'll add something in now.

Answer (score 0):

fn: defines a function obj but assigns no name to it. It is good when you want to create anonymous classes. to give it a name you need to use def:

```
(def greet (fn [name] (str "Hello, " name)))
```

On the other hand, defn, defines a function and gives it a name:

```
(defn greet [name] (str "Hello, " name))
```