# How can I filter JSON data by a given date in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I have many JSON objects, and I am trying to filter those objects by the date. These objects are being parsed from several JSON files using Cheshire.core, meaning that the JSON objects are in a collection. The date is being passed in in the following format "YYYY-MM-DD" (eg. 2015-01-10). I have tried using the filter and contains? functions to do this, but I am having no luck so far. How can I filter these JSON objects by my chosen date?

Current Clojure code:

```
(def filter-by-date?
    (fn [orders-data date-chosen]
      (contains? (get (get orders-data :date) :date) date-chosen)))


(prn (filter (filter-by-date? orders-data "2017-12-25")))
```

Example JSON object:

```
{
    "id":"05d8d404-b3f6-46d1-a0f9-dbdab7e0261f",
    "date":{
        "date":"2015-01-10T19:11:41.000Z"
    },
    "total":{
        "GBP":57.45
    }
}
```

JSON after parsing with Cheshire:

```
[({:id "05d8d404-b3f6-46d1-a0f9-dbdab7e0261f", 
:date {:date "2015-01-10T19:11:41.000Z"}, 
:total {:GBP 57.45}}) ({:id "325bd04-b3f6-46d1-a0f9-dbdab7e0261f", 
:date {:date "2015-02-23T10:15:14.000Z"}, 
:total {:GBP 32.90}})]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm going to assume you've parsed the JSON first into something like this:

```
(def parsed-JSON {:id "05d8d404-b3f6-46d1-a0f9-dbdab7e0261f",
                  :date {:date "2015-01-10T19:11:41.000Z"},
                  :total {:GBP 57.45}})
```

The main problem is the fact that the date as stored in the JSON contains time information, so you aren't going to be able to check it directly using equality.

You can get around this by using `clojure.string/starts-with?` to check for prefixes. I'm using `s/` here as an alias for `clojure.string`:

```
(defn filter-by-date [date jsons]
  (filter #(s/starts-with? (get-in % [:date :date]) date)
          jsons))
```

You were close, but I made a few changes:

- You can't use `contains?` like that. From the docs of `contains?`: `Returns true if key is present in the given collection, otherwise returns false`. It can't be used to check for substrings; it's used to test for the presence of a key in a collection.
- Use `-in` postfix versions to access nested structures instead of using multiple calls. I'm using `(get-in ...)` here instead of `(get (get ...))`.
- You're using `(def ... (fn []))` which makes things more complicated than they need to be. [This is essentially what `defn` does](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49185304/3000206), although `defn` also adds some more stuff as well.

---

To address the new information, you can just `flatten` the nested sequences containing the JSONs first:

```
(->> nested-json-colls ; The data at the bottom of the question
     (flatten)
     (filter-by-date "2015-01-10"))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and explanation. I'm using Cheshire.core to parse the JSON instead of clojure.data.json, so my JSON after parsing is in a slightly different structure to the one you suggested. I have updated my question to further clarify this

Comment: @podomunro What's the difference? They look identical to me.

Comment: I also forgot to mention that as there are multiple JSON files being parsed, the contents of the files are stored in a collection

Comment: @podomunro `filter-by-date` expects a collection of parsed JSONs already.

Comment: I finally got there. I've had to loop-recur through each JSON entry in the vector `[({id:....}) ({id:...})]` and give `filter-by-date` the first list of each vector, and then use `rest` when using recursion...

Comment: Awesome, I've got this working now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env boot

(defn deps [new-deps]
  (merge-env! :dependencies new-deps))

(deps '[[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
        [cheshire "5.8.0"]])

(require '[cheshire.core :as json]
         '[clojure.string :as str])

(def orders-data-str
"[{
    \"id\":\"987654\",
    \"date\":{
        \"date\":\"2015-01-10T19:11:41.000Z\"
    },
    \"total\":{
        \"GBP\":57.45
    }
},
{
    \"id\":\"123456\",
    \"date\":{
        \"date\":\"2016-01-10T19:11:41.000Z\"
    },
    \"total\":{
        \"GBP\":23.15
    }
}]")

(def orders (json/parse-string orders-data-str true))

(def ret (filter #(clojure.string/includes? (get-in % [:date :date]) "2015-01-") orders))
(println ret)  ; ({:id 987654, :date {:date 2015-01-10T19:11:41.000Z}, :total {:GBP 57.45}})
```

You can convert the date string to Date object using any DateTime library like joda-time and then do a proper filter if required.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I tried using your solution but I got a NullPointerException when trying to print "ret"

Comment: The json must then be not having proper keys. For example: ` (filter #(str/includes? (get-in % [:date :foo]) "2015-01-") orders)` gives NPE as the original json does not have `:foo` key.

Comment: I've updated my question to include an example of how the JSON is structured after parsing with Cheshire

Comment: The json data must be a collection. The parsed json in the example will work if you enclose it in a vector.

Comment: `(filter #(str/includes? (get-in % [:date :date]) "2015-01-") [{:id "05d8d404-b3f6-46d1-a0f9-dbdab7e0261f" :date {:date "2015-01-10T19:11:41.000Z"} :total {:GBP 57.45}}])`

Comment: That's a great point. I didn't mention that I'm using file-seq to parse multiple JSON files, meaning that when I parse each of those files, each file's data is being entered into a collection...

Answer (score 0):

[clj-time](https://github.com/clj-time/clj-time) has functions for parsing strings and comparing date-time objects. So you could do something like:

```
(ns filter-by-time-example
  (:require [clj-time.coerce :as tc]
            [clj-time.core :as t]))

(def objs [{"id" nil
            "date" {"date" "2015-01-12T19:11:41.000Z"}
            "total" nil}
           {"id" "05d8d404-b3f6-46d1-a0f9-dbdab7e0261f"
            "date" {"date" "2015-01-10T19:11:41.000Z"}
            "total" {"GBP" :57.45}}
           {"id" nil
            "date" {"date" "2015-01-11T19:11:41.000Z"}
            "total" nil}])

(defn filter-by-day
  [objs y m d]
  (let [start (t/date-time y m d)
        end (t/plus start (t/days 1))]
    (filter #(->> (get-in % ["date" "date"])
                  tc/from-string
                  (t/within? start end)) objs)))

(clojure.pprint/pprint (filter-by-day objs 2015 1 10)) ;; Returns second obj
```

If you're going to repeatedly do this (e.g. for multiple days) you could parse all dates in your collection into date-time objects with

```
(map #(update-in % ["date" "date"] tc/from-string) objs)
```

and then just work with that collection to avoid repeating the parsing step.

Answer (score 0):

```
(ns filter-by-time-example
  (:require [clj-time.format :as f]
            [clj-time.core :as t]
            [cheshire.core :as cheshire]))

(->> json-coll
     (map (fn [json] (cheshire/parse-string json true)))
     (map (fn [record] (assoc record :dt-date (f/format (get-in record [:date :date])))))
     (filter (fn [record] (t/after? (tf/format "2017-12-25") (:dt-date record))))
     (map (fn [record] (dissoc record :dt-date))))
```

Maybe something like this? You might need to change the filter for your usecase but as `:dt-time` is now a `jodo.DateTime` you can leverage all the `clj-time` predicates.